# Uncaught Error FBEventsCoercionError in Developer Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, google-tag-manager

I have deployed the Facebook Pixel base code via Tag Manager. I am getting this error and the FB Pixel is not loading properly. Subsequent FB Events such as Schedule events are also not working. It was working fine a few days ago.

I removed the pixel from GTM and then added the base pixel code in the head section, it gives me the same error.

Any idea on how we can resolve this?

[image]